# How to delay (about 0.5 second) before change text to password when user type a string into password field in html

Tags: javascript, html

How to delay (about 0.5 second) before change text to password when user type a string into password field in html. Please help me. I am coding web Java with Spring mvc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: What do you mean 'change text to password'?

Comment: when user type into password input field, last word that user type, will display about 0.5 second and then change to symbol of password (ie: ********).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get some kind of android style password field?

Like:
[*************w]

and after half second the last letter disappears resulting in this:
[**************]

I don't remember that being possible, if I understood you very well.
If I didn't than please explain further.

Comment: Yes, not only last word, but also any word that user input.
[w***********] --------0.5s------->[*************] 
[******w*****] --------0.5s------->[*************] 
[***********w] ---------0.5s------>[*************]

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's possible, I mean all that stuff does a browser.
If it is possible, it must require JavaScript.

I will do some research and see what I can do, If I succeed I will add another answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.